# Visual Studio 2017 SSRS templates and designer not working

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 I've installed:
 - SSDT
 - Data storage and processing module in installer
 - Microsoft Reporting Services Projects

Yet I have no .rdl report template in VS and .rdl files are opened with XML editor and no rdl designer

Is there other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create a report and access it in the asp.net MVC project. But for the .rdl reports I guess they work only in the Report Server Project. If I create a new project for .rdls only then designer works and reports can be created.